# Meteor 1.2.1 tutorial app ERROR on running "meteor"

Tags: meteor

I've searched everywhere and tried uninstalling and installing again. Here's what I get on the terminal:

=> Started proxy.
=> Started MongoDB.

```
/home/omar/.meteor/packages/meteor-        tool/.1.1.10.ki0ccv++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:245
                    throw(ex);
                          ^
Error: EPERM, symlink '/home/omar/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.10.ki0ccv++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules'
at Object.Future.wait (/home/omar/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.10.ki0ccv++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:398:15)
at /tools/fs/files.js:1331:28
at Object.wrapper (/tools/fs/files.js:1334:20)
at Builder.write (/tools/isobuild/builder.js:232:13)
at ServerTarget.write (/tools/isobuild/bundler.js:1750:15)
at /tools/isobuild/bundler.js:1847:30
at Object.keys.forEach.subBuilder (/tools/isobuild/bundler.js:1971:9)
at Array.forEach (native)
at /tools/isobuild/bundler.js:1963:26
at /tools/isobuild/bundler.js:2010:7
at /tools/isobuild/bundler.js:2287:22
at /tools/utils/buildmessage.js:268:13
at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (/tools/utils/fiber-helpers.js:114:14)
at /tools/utils/buildmessage.js:261:29
at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (/tools/utils/fiber-helpers.js:114:14)
at /tools/utils/buildmessage.js:259:18
at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (/tools/utils/fiber-helpers.js:114:14)
at /tools/utils/buildmessage.js:250:23
at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (/tools/utils/fiber-helpers.js:114:14)
at Object.capture (/tools/utils/buildmessage.js:249:19)
at Object.exports.bundle (/tools/isobuild/bundler.js:2128:31)
at /tools/runners/run-app.js:551:36
at time (/tools/tool-env/profile.js:232:28)
at Function.run (/tools/tool-env/profile.js:377:12)
at bundleApp (/tools/runners/run-app.js:541:34)
at [object Object]._.extend._runOnce (/tools/runners/run-app.js:594:35)
at [object Object]._.extend._fiber (/tools/runners/run-app.js:858:28)
at /tools/runners/run-app.js:396:12
```

Comment: @MatthiasEckhart Still no luck.

Comment: Well, it's definitely a permission error. Could you also please try to run: `chmod u=rwx -R ~/.meteor ~/.npm`?

Comment: @MatthiasEckhart well I just tried moving the whole folder to the home directory and Bam, it worked. I have no idea why though; If you do, the insight would be handy. Thanks anyway man

Comment: having the same problem

Comment: @altimit try changing your app directory to home for example. see what happens.

Comment: i did a meteor update, upgraded the dependencies, meteor-tool and underscore. problem solved @omar-kamal

Answer (score 0):

run this command first

```
meteor update --release 1.2
```

after that normally run the project.